# Storing Data on Parse for inApp purchase

Tags: ios, parse-platform, in-app-purchase

In an iOS app, I am trying to use Parse.com in a new(for me) way. I want to store data that is going to be made available to the user once an inApp purchase has been made.

---

I have gotten to the point I can put a dummy file on the server and get it into my app, once the purchase is done. But here comes my questions:
What kind of file am I supposed to upload on Parse.com? By trial and error I have noticed that a simple text (.txt) file did not work, on the other hand .png or .zip appears to be working extensions. The contents seems irrelevant. I have also read that it has to be one file. So if I want my user to get some text and some sound and a picture, I obviously have to package this into one file and unpackaged it after download. Am I supposed to put a .zip file or some other compressed format? And then how do I uncompress this after download? For example, say I want the user to get:

---

- 3 text files: A.txt, B.txt, C.xml
- 2 sound files: S1.mp3,S2.mp3
- 3 graphic files: Gr1.png,Gr2.png,Gr3.jpeg

How would I go? Some sample code or tutorial indication would be welcome.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

As per the docs you can save any binary data as long as the file doesn't exceed 10MB.

"The most common use case is storing images but you can also use it for documents, videos, music, and any other binary data (up to 10 megabytes)."

Below is an example of uploading three text files. For simplicities sake I have a class called TestClass with columns of type File named File1, File2, and File3.

For each file we will use the saveInBackgroundWithBlock method, so we know when our file has saved successfully and we can associate it with the proper TestClass column.

```
PFObject *testClass = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"TestClass"];

NSData *data = [@"This is the first text file!" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
PFFile *file = [PFFile fileWithName:@"file1.txt" data:data];

[file saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {
        testClass[@"File1"] = file;
        [testClass saveInBackground];        
    }
}];

data = [@"This is the second text file!" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
file = [PFFile fileWithName:@"file2.txt" data:data];

[file saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {
        testClass[@"File2"] = file;
        [testClass saveInBackground];        
    }
}];

data = [@"This is the third text file!" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
file = [PFFile fileWithName:@"file3.txt" data:data];

[file saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {
        testClass[@"File3"] = file;
        [testClass saveInBackground];        
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for this. If I am following right your examples and explanations, you are uploading 3 text files. Which is part of what I need to do, but that will not do the job completely, since in the case of in-app purchase I think I need a unique file. I can certainly find ways around and already tried, but I would like to know if there is a better way to do it. Packaging all the pieces with zip or?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not really that familiar with In-App Purchases. What do you need a unique file for?

Comment: For packaging text and sound.